# JNA to parameter that accepts pointers to different things

Tags: jna

Some ODBC apis are declared, in effect:

```
foo(void *buffer, int indicator_of_type);
```

Depending on what you pass in as the indicator, you might be passing a string, or you might be passing an integer.

There are also API's that work this way in the other direction. You always know what the data type is.

Presumably, I declare the pointer as a Pointer. Then, at Runtime, how do I obtain a suitable Pointer object that corresponds to some data I have (when passing it in), and what do I do in the opposite direction?

Comment: You can make as many Java-side mappings as you like, as long as JNA can figure out how to convert your Java type into a pointer.  Provide a few examples of native usage.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally digested enough documentation: you declare the JNA method param to take Pointer. In some cases, you can directly obtain that Pointer from your Structure, in others (basic numeric type) it seems that you create a Memory object and set the value into it.